# Do minor league baseball clubs pay the players?

Tags: baseball, finances, milb

MLB baseball teams send developing players to minor league affiliates.  Do the proceeds from minor league games to to play the players or the major league team, or does the owner of the minor league team use revenues solely for the expenses of the park?

Comment: minor league hockey and minor league baseball are structured *very* differently. Can you split this in 2?

Comment: @waxeagle I had no idea.  I'll change it.

Answer (score 2):

Minor league baseball players on affiliated clubs (non-independent leagues) are payed by their parent organizations.

Proceeds from the games go to a variety of other things like travel and stadium expenses.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_league_baseball#Current_system)

> Generally, the parent major league club pays the salaries and benefits of uniformed personnel (players and coaches) and bats and balls, while the minor league club pays for in-season travel and other operational expenses.